# Adding a title to a displaced image rollover

Tags: javascript

I have a simple image gallery (main images plus 4 thumbnails which on rollover trigger the main image swap) which needs to be extended to include a caption. The image swap function works as planned but I can't figure out how to 'tweak' the JS to allow the inclusion of a caption. Ideally I'd like to be able to add a title to the thumbnail and have it display beneath the main image.

```
<div class="contact">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/thumbs/img_cart1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/thumbs/img_cart2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/thumbs/img_cart3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/thumbs/img_cart4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/img_cart1.jpg" alt="" id="main-img" />

    </div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        // prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#gallery li img").hover(function(){
                $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumbs/', ''));
            });
            var imgSwap = [];
             $("#gallery li img").each(function(){
                imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumbs/', '');
                imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
            });
            $(imgSwap).preload();
        });
        $.fn.preload = function() {
            this.each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Any help would be greatfully received.

Thanks,
@rrfive

Answer (score 0):

Just make a JS object that includes an image and a caption to be displayed below... should work :)